# vim's taglist plugin not recognizing filetype for .sqC files

Tags: vim, taglist

I have been using ctags for a while. I recently downloaded taglist plugin for vim.
its cool. But i am facing one problem. While building the ctags file, i used langmap option to intrepret my embededed SQL files ( .sqC file extension) to C++.
But when i try to use the taglist it is not recognizing the filetype for these files and TlistOpen command doesnt open anything for it.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance
-Harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because embedded SQL is not supported by (exuberant) ctags ([see this](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/languages.html)). You might have to add support for embedded SQL yourself (see [extending taglist](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/extend.html) and [extending exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html)